# Why does eslint think this object is never reassigned? (prefer-const)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using eslint 4.17.0, which is reporting an issue that number is never reassigned, however I am reassigning it. Can someone explain why do I need to use const in this case?

```js
let test = {
    'number': 1,
    'string': 'asd',
};
test.number = 99;

console.log(test.number);
// output: 99
```

```json
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "google"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "prefer-const": 2

    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module"
    }
}
```

```
[eslint] 'test' is never reassigned. Use 'const' insted. (prefer-const)
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const

Comment: It's because `test` is *not* changed.  You're changing `test.number`, not `test`.

Comment: Also, your error message does not match your question title.  One says `test` (correctly) the title says "number" which is changed and is not in the warning.

Comment: Dang, I was looking for this rule. Somehow VSCode stopped suggesting this to me. Looks like it was just this project where I don't have my usual eslint rules ‍♂️. Without eslint it's like missing an eye.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ES6 const does not indicate that a value is ‘constant’ or immutable. A
>   const value can definitely change. The following is perfectly valid
>   ES6 code that does not throw an exception.

```js
const foo = {};
foo.bar = 42;
console.log(foo.bar);
// → 42
```

In your case, if you know that you are gonna change the properties, try using let.

Take a look here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const

Comment: My mistake the example is with leth, why eslint warning me that need to be const?

Comment: @Oto_Shan because `let` assumes that the variable value will be changed at some point of execution which in your example is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

From ESlint [Docs](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/prefer-const):

> If a variable is never modified, using the const declaration is better. *Const* declaration tells readers, “this variable is never
>   modified,” reducing cognitive load and improving maintainability.

```
        /*eslint prefer-const: 2*/
/*eslint-env es6*/

let a = 3;               /*error 'a' is never modified, use 'const' instead.*/
console.log(a);

// `i` is re-defined (not modified) on each loop step.
for (let i in [1,2,3]) {  /*error 'i' is never modified, use 'const' instead.*/
    console.log(i);
}

// `a` is re-defined (not modified) on each loop step.
for (let a of [1,2,3]) { /*error 'a' is never modified, use 'const' instead.*/
    console.log(a);
}
```