# What advantages does using const over let and var give us?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know the difference between `const`, `let`, and `var`:

- Scope
- Lack of hoisting
- The value of `const` variable cannot be changed.

But why ever use `const`? Besides from the age old example with PI as 3.14, is there any other advantage then "cleaner code", which I find `const` is really good for? Is there some efficiency upside to it, because the browser doesn't have to edit the variable?

Comment: I'll flip that on you - what's the advantage of using `let` if you're not going to change the value?

Comment: `And the value of  const variable cannot be changed` <= didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750029/whats-the-point-of-declaring-a-const-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086633/why-most-of-the-time-should-i-use-const-instead-of-let-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707353/number-is-never-reassigned-use-const-instead-prefer-const, blah blah blah. This is a trivially-researchable question, on SO, and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there to help us humans understand the code better and make fewer bugs. By labelling something as `const` instead of `let`, you let other developers (including future you) know that it won't be reassigned. And if you accidentally do so, your IDE will tell you there's a problem, thus prompting you to either stop reassigning it, or change it to `let` to indicate that you really do intend for it to be reassigned.

Comment: Ok. I never thought about the code conservation. That's a good point